# Logstash is unable to access different user directories

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, chmod, logstash-configuration, chown

I'm having trouble with logstash log gathering.
For gathering logs from Oracle databases, I utilized logstash.
Because the directory owner and user are oracle, and I can alter the user on oracle databases, logstash can access them. The logstash service is started by the root user.
I have a fantastic concept, however I need the logstash different users such as root, logstash, Oracle, and so on. Cary those users, and if the log stash finds an oracle user directory, it changes the user from one of them to an oracle user, and if the log stash finds a root owner directory, it changes the user from one of them to the root one, and it gets or collects the log. Does my idea have a chance of getting a response like
chown oracle:oracle root:oinstall logstash oracle:oinstall logstash

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do and what is the issue, can you give a real example? But first, if you are running logstash as a service, you should use the `logstash` user, it is **not** recommended to run logstash as `root`, second, can you share your logstash configuration? If you want logstash to read files, you need to give read permission to the logstash user to the files and paths.

Comment: i just want to collect log from deferent source one of databases trace log.

Comment: You need to share an example and the configs you are using.